# A-frame physics dynamic body not functioning properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, aframe, webvr

frame and trying to create a game.

At first I was trying to make objects fall from sky and go back up but was not able to by purely using this

```
box.setAttribute('position',
```

I had to remove the attr dynamic body with this

```
$("#box").removeAttr("dynamic-body");
//use set attribute function 
$("#box").attr("dynamic-body","true");
```

This worked but now I want the box to go back to sky if anybody points the cursor over it click on it for that I am using this inside the a-box
    `<a-box some-attrs><a-animation attribute="position" begin="click" to="7 4 -3"></a-animation> </a-box>` but its not working and I guess its the same problem of using dynamic body with the box.

if you guys know any way better than this please let me know how can I do modification like animation and set attributes without removing the dynamic body attr.

-Thanks

Comment: I am new to A frame and trying to create a game using physics in a-frame.

Comment: I never used that before but are you trying to say that when wherever there is a click event of the cursor inside the box, the object should be cloned and behave as the original object?

Comment: I don't want to clone the box or the object, I simply want to teleport the entity whenever it is clicked. but it is not happening due to the physics component and the dynamic body attribute attached with the entity

Comment: In that case i believe that you are dynamically changing the positions of the object?

Comment: yups. I want to change the position whenever it gets clicked

Comment: Would request you to post more relevant codes on this

Answer (score 1):

You can try pausing the entity with box.pause() and that may stop he dynamic body behavior from running to allow you to reset the position. But the most reliable way is to detach the dynamic body component, make position modifications, and then reattach it.